# How to know if my application is running over a JBoss server?

Tags: java, gwt, jboss, jetty

I am developing a GWT application.

And I would like to know if I am running over a Jboss instance or over a Jetty instance.

This is because if I am running over Jetty it means that I am running the dev mode and I need to redirect to MyModule.html?codeserver... but if I am running over Jboss I need to redirect to MyModule.html

But I can't figure how can I know if I am running over Jetty or over Jboss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to find out the webserver on which your application is running, in your application code. Instead you can have a discriminating parameter set in the context of your application with different values for different servers.

E.g.

For JBoss, the server.xml can contain a parameter in the context definition as follows:

```
<Context ...>
    ...
    <Parameter name="applicationStage" value="prod" />
    ...
</Context>
```

and for Jetty, the same context parameter would go into its jetty.xml but the value as "devo".

Comment: Is there a way to access context-params in a non servlet class? I have a ServerUtils and a static method boolean isDevelopment(); And I would like to keep it in this way if it is possible :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know wether you are running production or development mode, then try

```
GWT.isProdMode();
```

Only works client-side of course.

Comment: yeap, but I need this in back, in appengine I have this SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Development. I am looking something like this.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really any simple way to determine what application server you're running on (to my knowledge). You could check some system properties to determine this.

JBoss:

```
jboss.server.name
```

Jetty:

```
jetty.home
```

Although I do not encourage having logic determined by your environment as Vikdor mentions in his answer. His suggestion would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

In a JSP,

```
Server is <%= application.getServerInfo()%>
```

or use

```
Server is ${pageContext.servletContext.serverInfo}
```

in a Servlet,

```
String server = getServletContext().getServerInfo();
```